# как отображать код файла на сайте а не скачивать

Tags: файлы, github

как на сайте реализовать штуку как на гитхабе чтобы при переходе к примеру по ссылке файлу .py он не скачивался а отображал код как в raw.github

Comment: Отдавать файл как text, без заголовков "скачивания", либо отдавать как html в <pre> тегах. Ответ зависит от среды.

Comment: не типа смари, ты к примеру грузишь файл на гит репо, и потом к этому файлу можно получить доступ через домен который ты привязал как пример пусть будет spyd3r.tk ты к примеру хочешь обратиться через этот домен к файлу pasts.py т.е в моем случае это https://spyd3r.tk/modules/pasts.py мне нужно чтобы после того как юзер открывает эту ссылку файл не скачивался а отображал код

Comment: я не хочу типа создавать еще один файл индекс html в который я буду вкладывать код своего файла

Comment: я просто хочу залить файл в папку с модулями и в последствии отображать его не скачивая

Comment: Надо что бы файл отдавал не web-сервер, а программа-шлюз.  Программа имеет возможность управлять заголовками, а диспечер будет отдавать всегда как файл, он по-другому не умеет. Либо надо использовать какие-нибудь CMS-ки управления файлами. Это реализуется программой.

Comment: По идее txt файлы будут отображаться "как есть".

Comment: nginx autoindex + при отдаче выставлять файлам content-type = 'text/plain'